# How many even 3 digit numbers contain at least one 7.

Tags: combinatorics, decimal-expansion

How many even 3 digit numbers contain at least one 7.
I got 126, but it was not an answer choice for the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you get 126?

Comment: number of 3 digit numbers - number of odd numbers - numbers that DONT contain a 7. But i feel ive messed up along the way.

Comment: 900-450-324=126 those were the numbers i came up with, the answer choices are 90,450,25, 125

Comment: How do you get 324 for number of even numbers with no 7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The $7$ can't be in the ones place if the number is even.  That leaves the tens and hundreds place.

For all hundreds except the $700$s, there are five evens with at least one $7$: $n70, n72, n74, n76, n78$.

That accounts for $40$.

For the $700$s, there are $50$:  $700, 702, 704, ... 796, 798$.

So there are $90$ total.

Comment: thanks man, appreciate the help.

Comment: My pleasure.  I am curious though how you arrived at your first answer.  What did you do to come up with the $324$?

Answer (score 8):

Count the number of $3$ digit even numbers that do not contain $7$ and subtract from the total number of $3$ digit even numbers.

> Let $xyz$ be the $3$ digit even number. Total number of $3$ digit even numbers is $450$, since $x$ has $9$ options, $y$ has $10$ options and $z$ has $5$ options. To obtain the number of $3$ digit even numbers that do not contain $7$, $x$ has $8$ options, while $y$ has $9$ options and $z$ continues to have $5$ options, i.e., $8 \times 9 \times 5 = 360$. Hence, the number of $3$ digit even numbers that contain at-least one $7$ is $450 - 360 = 90$.

Comment: Not sure why this one was downvoted.  Maybe the downvoter didn't notice that you "hid" the full solution.  +1

Answer (score 8):

The final (units) digit is even, and there are five choices for that independent of whatever else happens - so the answer must be divisible by five.

There are $450$ even numbers with three digits. If there is no seven the hundreds digit is one of eight (no zero or seven), and the tens digit is one of nine (no seven). So $8\times 9\times 5$ with no seven - that is $360$ leaving $90$ with a seven.

Comment: Clever way of solving the problem. +1

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are $10$ digits, $0$ to $9$.
The probability of a $3$ digit even number without a $7$ is $$8/9 \times 9/10 \times 5/10 = 360/900$$
Which is $360$ even numbers without a $7$.
So the number with at least one $7$ is $450 - 360 = 90$.

Answer (score 1):

A more numerical approach using python

```
In [2]: import itertools

In [3]: I=itertools.ifilter(lambda x:"7" in str(x), range(100,1000,2))

In [4]: len(list(I))
Out[4]: 90
```